# how to add another where condition in this zf2 db/sql : $select->where->in('id', $this->idsArray);

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

Im trying to filter the company list by area , in the CompanyMapper, i want to add area condition in this select statement , i tried several method but every thing got error

I truing to achieve result using zf2 Tablegateway in COMPANYMAPPER.

how can i achieve the result to similar below :

```
Select * 
From  Companies
where  'id' IN  ($this->idsArray) 
  AND   'locality=localityId'
```

The result should be companies list filtered by locality id .

and  code in the companymapper currently is as given below , how to another condition in to this $select ?

```
public function fetchCompaniesByArea($companies_found, $area, $limit) {
    $this->idsArray=$companies_found;

    return $this->hydrate(
                    $this->select(function (Select $select) {
                       $select->where->in('id', $this->idsArray);

                    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more where condition.

> return $this->hydrate($this->select(
>      function (Select $select) {
>
> > ```
> >   $select->where->in('id', $this->idsArray);
> >
> >  //Like this
> >  $select->where('locality=localityId');
> > ```
> >
> > })
> >     );